# How to detect if objects are on top of each other?

Tags: image-processing, graphics

Lets say we know the co-ordinates of each object in a camera co-ordinate systems. How do we find out if some object is on top of each other? My idea is: Compare each object and point with one another.For two different points on different objects check if the X and Z values are the same and the difference between the Y value is within some threshold. What do you guys think?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you edit your question to clarify what you mean by "on top"?  Do you mean, higher (in distance from the ground)?  Or do you mean, occludes (i.e., the view of one object is partly or completely hidden by the other, from the camera's perspective)?  Also, what prevents you from knowing whether your answer is correct or not?  Have you tried working through some examples to see if it seems to give the right answer?  Have you tried writing a proof, or a proving that it works correctly in special cases (such as all possible scenes containing only two objects)?